# Hosting ASP.NET Website on Local Machine

Tags: asp.net, localhost, iis-5

I developed a website using Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010 in Windows XP as purpose of training. Now I need to run it on different computers in the same network. I think for that I should host it on IIS.

How can I host it on IIS 5.1?

Comment: I need more detail and i think you need also a system administrator.
You have a pc with IIS and a folder with the site. The folder has the correct rights (or everyone full control). Now you can configure your site in IIS under Default web site and you can get it as "http://localhost/yoursite" or create a new web site as "http://www.yourwebsite.it" and map it to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file

Comment: I created a virtual directory "chat" and when am callining "localhost/chat" it displays error " Failed to access IIS metabase."

Comment: Run

 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i